# Format specific datetime string to datetime datatype in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

I have a string which stands for a specific format of datetime.
Format: **yyyymmddhhmmss**
For example: 20220504111621

I want it to convert to a SQL Server datetime datatype: **yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss** (Format 120)

Is there a way to do that?
I tried something like:

```
select [SYNC_TIME] 
replace(convert(varchar, [SYNC_TIME],101),'/','') + replace(convert(varchar, [SYNC_TIME],108),':','')
FROM [DB].[dbo].[DATABASENAME]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lots of ways, you could use `stuff` to format the string and convert:

```
declare @string varchar(15)='20220504111621'
select Convert(datetime,Stuff(Stuff(Stuff(@string,9,0,' '),12,0,':'),15,0,':'),112)
```